# Java class extend another class using reflection (bukkit)

Tags: java, reflection, minecraft, extends, bukkit

I am trying to make an Anvil GUI for my bukkit plugin. I am trying to make my code cross-version compatible. However the class `FakeAnvil` need to extend the class `ContainerAnvil`, and this class is in the NMS package... is there any way that I can extend the class with reflection?

Here's my code:

```
package me.raymondliu1;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
//These five import is making the plugin not cross-version compatible
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.BlockPosition;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.ContainerAnvil;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.EntityHuman;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.PlayerInventory;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.World;


//problem 1
public final class FakeAnvil extends ContainerAnvil {
static Class<?> entityHumanClass;
static Class<?> BlockPositionClass;
static Class<?> ContainerAnvilClass;
static Constructor<?> bpc;
static Constructor<?> cac;
static{
    try {
        entityHumanClass = getNMSClass("EntityHuman");
        BlockPositionClass = getNMSClass("BlockPosition");
        ContainerAnvilClass = getNMSClass("ContainerAnvil");
        cac = ContainerAnvilClass.getConstructor(PlayerInventory.class,World.class,BlockPositionClass,entityHumanClass);
        bpc = BlockPositionClass.getConstructor(int.class,int.class,int.class);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private static Class<?> getNMSClass(String nmsClassString) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    String version = Bukkit.getServer().getClass().getPackage().getName().replace(".", ",").split(",")[3] + ".";
    String name = "net.minecraft.server." + version + nmsClassString;
    Class<?> nmsClass = Class.forName(name);
    return nmsClass;
}
public FakeAnvil(Object entityHuman) throws Exception {
    //Problem 2
    super((PlayerInventory)entityHumanClass.getField("inventory").get(entityHuman), (World)entityHumanClass.getField("inventory").get("world"), (BlockPosition)bpc.newInstance(0,0,0), (EntityHuman)entityHuman);

}
@Override
public boolean a(EntityHuman entityHuman) {    
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: You can implements two versions of the class and only load the one that is compatible with the detected version. Java classes are loaded on first use, therefore unloadable classes don't make problems until you try to load it.

Comment: In bukkit popular solution is to create module per each NMS version and common API for them, so you only later load proper module using reflections and use it via common api, other idea is to create class at runtime using libraries like ByteBuddy or Javassist

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't make a class inherit from another class or interface using reflection.

However, you can modify contents in the NMS package (not recommended) and use it instead.

Comment: Is creating a FakeAnvil class for different version of minecraft possible? Will I get errors because of the classes imported?

Comment: It should be all fine as long as you can get the NMS class.